# Redraw bootstrap modal on hide or open

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Using bootstrap (4.x) modal and running into redraw issues. When the modal is reopened after cancelling, it still retains the state (e.g. validation messages, red rectangles, etc). It's even worse because the "form-control" classes are removed and the input elements get resized.

I am using the `show.bs.modal` and `hide.bs.modal` event handlers to painstakingly add the removed classes back and remove the validation message/validation visual elements.

Is there any function in bootstrap that can redraw the modal as it was when the page was initially loaded without refreshing the entire page?

Comment: One way would be to -> Save the original modal data which was in the initial first-page load in a `var` and load in back in using jQuery `.html` method to avoid reloading the whole page.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Actually there is no data when the modal is initially shown.  The modal just has three dropdown elements, a text box and a datatime picker set to user's current time.  So there is no data to save.  If the user makes mistakes, sees the validation errors, cancels and reopens the modal, I want the modal to be just like when the page loaded.

Comment: are you able to show this example in some sort of video or screenshots to help us understand the user data and data after page loads.